# How to update an existing object in parse following a button click? (JavaScript SDK)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Using Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

The purpose of the below function is:

a/ Return a list of users that the current user needs to respond to a friend request.
b/ When they click cancel, the current object state changes from "Pending" to "Declined"

Part (a) works as required. Part (b) is returning the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

I presume this is because it cannot find "status" to change and save it from "Pending" to "Declined" ?

I've blocked out the area of code that I think is not working, but cannot get around this and need some help ;-)

```
                     //////////Returns list of Friends pending a response///////////////////
                         function FriendsPending() {

                            $('#containerFriends').empty();
                            $('#containerFriendsRejected').empty();
                            $('#containerFriendsRequestSent').empty();
                            $('#containerFriendsConnected').empty();
                            $('#userimgs').empty();

                            var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
                            var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

                            var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
                            query.include('toUser');
                            query.include('SentTo');
                            query.include("myBadge");
                            query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
                            query.equalTo("status", "Pending");

                            query.find({
                                success: function(results) {
                                    var friends = [];
                                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                        friends.push({
                                            imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                                            friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                                            username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                                            userId: results[i].get('toUser').id,
                                            status: results[i].get('status').id


                                        });


                                    }
                                    var select = document.getElementById("FriendsPending");
                                    $.each(friends, function(i, v) {
                                        var opt = v.username;
                                        var el = document.createElement("option");
                                        el.textContent = opt;
                                        el.value = opt;
                                        select.appendChild(el);
                                    })

                                    $('#containerFriendsPending').empty();
                                    _.each(friends, function(item) {
                                        var wrapper = $('<div class="portfolio-item-thumb one-third"></div>');
                                        wrapper.append('<img class="responsive-image friendImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />'+ '<br>');
                                        wrapper.append('<div class="tag">' + item.username + '</div>');
                                        $('#containerFriends').append(wrapper);
                                        wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="btn btn-success mrs">' + 'Accept' + '</div>');
                                        wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="btn btn-danger mrs decline">' + 'Decline' + '</div>');
                                        $('#containerFriendsPending').append(wrapper);
//////Code with issues//////////////
                                        $(document).on('click', function() {
                                            $(".decline").click(function() {
                                                status: results[i].get('status').id
                                                status.set("status", "Declined");
                                                console.log(status);
///////////////////////////
                                                status.save(null, {
                                                    success: function(results) {
                                                            // The object was saved successfully.
                                                            location.reload();
                                                        },
                                                        error: function(contact, error) {
                                                            // The save failed.
                                                            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                                                            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                                                        }
                                                    });


                                            });

                                        });
                                    });

},
error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
}
});

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
status: results[i].get('status').id
```

You are getting that error because you are trying to call `get` on `results[i]` which is undefined because `i` is undefined.

Also, the line itself is not a valid expression. If you want to assign something to a variable called "status", this is the correct syntax:

```
var status = ...
```

Further, it looks like you are treating status as an object, rather than just a field.

```
status: results[i].get('status')
```

When you want to change the status later, you need to keep a reference to the original fetched object. E.g.:

```
friends.push({
    imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
    friendRequestId: results[i].id,
    username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
    userId: results[i].get('toUser').id,
    status: results[i].get('status'),
    fetchedObject: results[i]
});
```

Then later when you want to set the status on that object to declined:

```
item.fetchedObject.set("status", "Declined");
```

It is the fetchedObject you then want to save:

```
item.fetchedObject.save( // );
```

Comment: thanks, that looks like it moves me in the right direction, its returning a "Uncaught TypeError: Object Pending has no method 'set' " error now though, any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you don't have the full status object. Fetch it or include it in the original query.

Comment: Sorry, from looking at your code I thought status was a class on its own. I updating the answer now.

Comment: thank you so much, this is perfect - Thank you for explaining it so clearly.